# read firestore value from document doesn't work

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to read the a **value** from **firestore** document. But it doesn't work for me and I don't know where is the problem.should i use **get()** or **realtime updates.**
I tried both but doesn't work for me 
*this is my code.* 
I confirmed my positions by using toast and the are ok.

How to solve this problem?

```
public class SingleAdActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String x;
    String a;
    String z;
    String coname;
    TextView Co_Name;

    private ListenerRegistration listenerRegistration;
    DocumentReference firebaseFirestore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_ad);
        Co_Name = findViewById(R.id.SingleAd_CoName);
        ad_discription = findViewById(R.id.disrcibe_ad);
        phone_number = findViewById(R.id.phone);
        x = getIntent().getStringExtra("single_ad_position");
        a = getIntent().getStringExtra("single_ad_categoryP");
        z = getIntent().getStringExtra("documentId");


        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("MainCategories")
                .document(String.valueOf(a))
                .collection("Ads")
                .document(z);

        @Override
        protected void onStart () {
            super.onStart();
            listenerRegistration = firebaseFirestore
                    .addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void
                        onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                            if (e != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(SingleAdActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return;
                            }
                            assert documentSnapshot != null;
                            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {

                                coname = documentSnapshot.getString("CompanyName");
                                Co_Name.setText(coname);

                            } else {

                                // Co_Name.setText(a);

                            }
                        }
                    });

        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop () {
            super.onStop();
            listenerRegistration.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Amr, please add your database structure.

Comment: Good to hear that you are seeing that video but this sounds to be another problem. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question containing an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other users can help you. Regarding this issue, can you please add your database structure?

Comment: ok,  I will prepare it  as screenshot.

Comment: That's good. Please notify me when you have added.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore firestoreDb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
firestoreDb..collection(yourCollection)
                .document(yourDocument)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Object yourObject = task.getResult().toObject(YourClassName.class);
                        } else {
                            if(task.getException() != null)
                            {
                                task.getException().printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });
```